# How to pass Error Message to Route from a different Controller in Ember js

Tags: ember.js

Let, I have two routes and two controllers namely *login* and *signup*
If I signup successfully then I want to perform transition to the route login with a *success* message as parameter,

> /app/signup/controller.js

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        signup: function(){
            let _this = this;
            let successMessage = 'successfully registered';
            var credentials = this.getProperties('name','identification','password');
            let list = this.store.createRecord('user', {
                name: credentials.name,
                email: credentials.identification,
                password: credentials.password
            });
            list.save().then(function(){
                _this.transitionToRoute('login','successMessage');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

> app/login/template.hbs

```
<body>
  {{successMessage}}
</body>
```

> /app/router.js

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login');
  this.route('signup');
});

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you sort of have 3 options:

1. Use a route param (query param or positional)
2. Use a service to manage login stuff, and read some computed property from the service representing your state / message from your login controller
3. Use a flash/toast style UI where the message lives outside of the app view/component hierarchy

Personally, for where you want to display your message, I'd go for #2, which would look like this:

```
// app/services/user-session.js
import Service from '@ember/service';

export default class extends Service {
  successMessage = null;

  signup(name, id, password) {
    // logic
    this.set('successMessage', 'yay');
  }
}

// app/controllers/signup.js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { service } from '@ember-decorators/service';
import { action } from '@ember-decorators/object';

export default class extends Controller {
  @service userSession;

  @action
  signup() {
    this.userSession.signup(...);
    this.transition...
  }
}

// app/controllers/login.js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { service } from '@ember-decorators/service';
import { readOnly } from '@ember-decorators/object/computed';

export default class extends Controller {
  @service userSession;

  @readOnly('userSession.successMessage') successMessage;
}
```

Or, in the old syntax:

```
// app/services/user-session.js
import Service from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
  successMessage: null,

  signup(name, id, password) {
    // logic
    this.set('successMessage', 'yay');
  }
});

// app/controllers/signup.js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
  userSession: service(),

  actions: {
    signup() {
      this.userSession.signup(...);
      this.transition...
    }
  }
});

// app/controllers/login.js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { readOnly } from '@ember/object/computed';

export default Controller.extend({
  userSession: service(),

  successMessage: readOnly('userSession.successMessage')
});
```

hope this helps